# Do bodies disappear in Doom?

Tags: doom-2016

In the original games killed enemies never disappear as far as I know, levels can be literally filled with hundreds of corpses. [Doom 3 was criticized for disintegrating dead creatures](https://www.gamespot.com/reviews/doom-3-review/1900-6104145/) — unfortunately the latest Doom appears to be comparable in this aspect (based on the [PC demo](http://store.steampowered.com/app/379720/DOOM/) which may not be up to date).

Do all enemies disappear instantly even in the technically superior PC version?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

Bodies don't disappear *instantly*, but they do burn away after a few seconds.

Comment: The blood and guts tend to hang around though!